# How to convert a 5-bytes hex number to 10base number and represent it in C-type string?

Tags: c

I have a hex number which consist of 5 bytes: 0xEEDDCCBBAA. This number is stored in an array: [0xEE 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA]. I want to convert it to 10base decimal number and represent it as a C-type string: "1025923398570". (0xEEDDCCBBAA is equal to 1,025,923,398,570)

One problem is my system only supports max. 32-bits type variable, so I cannot have a single variable to store this number or perform any type of operation larger than 32-bits. For example I cannot do:

```
unsigned long long val = 0xeeddccbbaa;
unsigned char buf[50];
sprintf(buf, "%d", val);
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: As my question seems confusing so I wrote it again.

Comment: `unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long) array[0] << 32 | (unsigned long) array[1] << 24 | (unsigned long) array[1] << 16 | (unsigned) array[2] << 8 | | (unsigned) array[0];  char buf[11]; sprintf(buf, "%010llX", x);`

Comment: `EE DDCC BBAAh` is `1.025.923.398.570` and not `64.120.208.298`

Comment: @chux the problem is I do not have "unsigned long long" in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could create a generic routine to handle any size byte array.

```
#include <string.h>

char *convert_10base_decimal_number(char *dest, size_t dsize, unsigned char *a,
    size_t asize) {

  if (dsize == 0)
    return NULL;
  char *d = dest + dsize - 1;
  *d = '\0';
  size_t ai = 0;
  do {
    // mod 10
    unsigned carry = 0;
    for (size_t i = ai; i < asize; i++) {
      carry = carry * 256 + a[i];
      a[i] = carry / 10;
      carry %= 10;
    }
    if (d == dest)
      return NULL;
    d--;
    *d = carry + '0';
    if (a[ai] == 0)
      ai++;
  } while (ai < asize);
  memmove(dest, d, dsize - (d - dest));
  return (dest);
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned char a[] = { 0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA };
  char buf[50];

  puts(convert_10base_decimal_number(buf, sizeof buf, a, sizeof a));
  // 1025923398570

  return 0;
}
```

This method does consume the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
long x,y;
x = a[0] | (a[1] << 8) | (a[2] << 16) || (a[3] << 24)
y = a[4]
```

So `x` is `0xEEDDCCBB` and `y` is `0xAA`
You can use sprintf to convert x to a string and then concatenate it to y.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm reading this for the 3rd time and I don't understand it as you do.

Comment: `x` should have an unsigned type.

Comment: I am sorry if the title is confusing, anybody can suggest a title for me? English is not my first language. Thank you

Comment: I have written my question again. Please be noticed that one of my main constraint is I do not have variable larger than 32-bits, such as the "long long".

Answer (score 0):

The real challenge here is the conversion to base `10`, using 32 bits arithmetic only.

Let your 64 bits number be `N = M.2^32 + L`, and use the decomposition `X = 10 (X/10) + (X%10) = 10 Xq + Xr`.

Then,

```
N = (10.Mq + Mr)(10.429496729 + 6) + (10.Lq + Lr) = 100.429496729.Mq + 10.6.Mq + 10.429496729.Mr + 6.Mr + 10.Lq + Lr.
```

From this we derive the unit digit

```
Nr = N%10 = (6.Mr + Lr) % 10,
```

and the quotient

```
Nq = N/10 = 10.429496729.Mq + 6.Mq + 429496729.Mr + Lq + (6.Mr + Lr) / 10.
```

In the latter expression, the first two terms are just `Mq.2^32`, so you divide the most significant doubleword by `10`. The next term will fit in 32 bits as `Mr` is at most `9` and `429496729.9` is less than `2^32`. I don't think that a carry from the LSD to the MSD can arise, but this should be double-checked.

You can continue this division process to extract the next digits, until the MSD becomes 0 (then continue with the LSD alone).

In your example case

```
M = 0xEE = 238 = 10 * 23 + 8, N = 0xDDCCBBAA = 3721182122 = 10 * 372118212 + 2
```

The unit digit is `Nr = (6 * 8 + 2) % 10 = 0`.

The quotient by `10` is

```
M' = 238 / 10 = 23, L' = 429496729 * 8 + 372118212 + (6 * 8 + 2) / 10 = 3808092049.
```

(As you can check, `23 * 2^32 + 3808092049= 102592339857`.)

The next digit is `N'r = (6 * 3 + 9) % 10 = 7`.

The quotient by `10` is

```
M" = 23 / 10 = 2, L" = 429496729 * 3 + 380809204 + (6 * 3 + 9) / 10 = 1669299393.
```

(As you can check, `2 * 2^32 + 1669299393 = 10259233985`.)

The next digit is `N"r = (6 * 2 + 3) % 10 = 5`.

The quotient by `10` is

```
M"' = 2 / 10 = 0, L"' = 429496729 * 2 + 166929939 + (6 * 2 + 3) / 10 = 1025923398.
```

As `M"' = 0`, you can now continue the conversion in pure 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[5] = {0xEE, 0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA};

// @Shmoopy's piece of code
int x = a[0] | (a[1] << 8) | (a[2] << 16) || (a[3] << 24);
int y = a[4];

// making long long from x and y, where y is the mo;
long long z = (long long)y << 32 | x;

// conversion of long long to string with base 10 (2^64 has max 19 decimal digits)
char str[20] = {};
lltoa(z, str, 10);
printf("The number is %s.\n", str);
```

Comment: I just tested my system does not have "long long" type varible. "int" in my system is 16bits, and "long" is 32bits. It is a M0 core microprocessor.

Comment: do you have any library function for 64 bit integer computation?